# Execute a script when moving to it's dir?

Tags: bash, shell, virtualenv, zsh

I'm playing around with virtualenv and pip, but I find it quite restrictive to have to "source bin/activate" each time I come into a virtualenv dir. 
So I'd like to automate it. Any ideas of a way to execute a script once we change to it's dir, or a shell features enabling this behavior?

Comment: which shell are you using, bash? If so, tag this question with bash and you'll have a answer in 30 seconds. It might also help to indicate OS, Linux/Unix/SomethingElse?

Comment: My bad, I'm actually using zsh, on Linux and Osx.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I never use the source bin/activate, but always use the full path to the executable in the virtualenv if I want to execute something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this in your `.bash_profile`::

```
has_virtualenv() {
    if [ -e .venv ]; then
        workon `cat .venv`
    fi
}
venv_cd () {
    cd "$@" && has_virtualenv
}
alias cd="venv_cd"
```

It replaces default `cd` command with a script which 1) does the actual `cd`, 2) checks for `.venv` file inside new directory, 3) if it's found, assumes that the file contains virtual environment name and executes `` workon `cat .venv` ``.

`workon` command is a replacement for plain `source bin/activate`; it's provided by [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) and has some niceties like `postactivate` hook. See project page for more details.

That piece of code above I found via [post](http://justinlilly.com/blog/2009/mar/28/virtualenv-wrapper-helper/) by Justin Lilly. See also [tips](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/src/b770006fb551/docs/en/tips.rst) in virtualenvwrapper's docs for some other cool stuff.